# c# Telegram bot api Отправить альбом IAlbumInputMedia

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Нужно отправить сообщение которое содержит фото и видео в виде альбома.

Пример кода [SendMediaGroup](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot/blob/e09ed3f20ba6a1f05ac0ea8c2e3dccc3550a641f/test/Telegram.Bot.Tests.Integ/Sending%20Messages/AlbumMessageTests.cs#L117)

```
 Message[] messages;
        using (Stream
            stream0 = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Constants.PathToFile.Videos.GoldenRatio),
            stream1 = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Constants.PathToFile.Videos.MoonLanding),
            stream2 = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Constants.PathToFile.Photos.Bot)
        )
        {
            IAlbumInputMedia[] inputMedia =
            {
                new InputMediaVideo(new InputMedia(stream0, "GoldenRatio.mp4"))
                {
                    Caption = "Golden Ratio",
                    Height = 240,
                    Width = 240,
                    Duration = 28,
                },
                new InputMediaVideo(new InputMedia(stream1, "MoonLanding.mp4"))
                {
                    Caption = "Moon Landing"
                },
                new InputMediaPhoto(new InputMedia(stream2, "bot.gif"))
                {
                    Caption = "Bot"
                },
            };

            messages = await BotClient.SendMediaGroupAsync(
                chatId: _fixture.SupergroupChat.Id,
                inputMedia: inputMedia
            );
        }
```

Код на примере выше подходит если заранее известно сколько файлов нужно отправить.

У меня есть папка, в ней содержиться какое-то количество файлов (часть изображений часть видео) их я хочу отправить в виде сообщения.

Как **inputMedia** можно заполнить в цикле?

Спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Сделай два списка

```
List<Stream>
List<InputMediaVideo>
```

В цикле пройди по всем файлам и создай stream и потом обьект InputMedia, добавь оба в списки.

Конвертируешь список в масив и отправляешь.

После отправки вручную идешь по потоках и закрываешь их